# Can you get Identifying information about the receiving iOS device in an AirDrop transfer?

Tags: ios, airdrop

Can you get Identifying information about the receiving iOS device in an AirDrop transfer? UDID, Owner's name, the info that shows up in the screen when you proceed to send the data, something? I want to keep a log.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently not possible. You should file an [enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/%E2%80%8E) with Apple explaining why they should add this.